# How to Interpolate Ranges in Dart List

Tags: dart

I have a Dart `List` of `int` like this:

```dart
List<int> myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
```

I have a couple known index ranges like this:

```dart
(5,9)
(13,16)
```

My goal is to end up with the ranges that fill in the rest of the list:

```dart
(0,4) <-- new
(5,9)
(10,12) <-- new
(13,16)
(17,20) <-- new
```

The context is I am trying to style different parts of a string based on the range, where (5,9) is bold, etc.

How can I deduce a set of ranges like this in Dart?

### Update

Here is what I've tried so far. If I remove the ranges I know about:

```dart
list.removeRange(5, 9);
```

...I am left with the rest:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20]
```

But now the indexes have changed, so I can't remove the next range:

```dart
list.remove(13,16) <-- Wrong
```

I want to remove the ranges I know about and create new ranges based on what's left. I recently came across `sublist(5,9)` which returns the values from a range, but I'm still unsure how to move forward.

I think what I really need is some kind of way to split by range. But `splitBetween` doesn't do what I expected:

```dart
list.splitBetween((first, second) => first == 5 && second == 9);
```

It doesn't break the list up like I had hoped.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the known ranges are non-overlapping, you can trivially sort them, and then finding the missing ranges should be fairly straightforward.  What have you tried?

Comment: Your representation of ranges does not support the operations you want to make. That usually means you should look for a different representation. Consider representing the ranges as a sorted list of `(int first, int last)` pairs, each representing a sub-range. Then do the operations on those ranges. Or something even cleverer, depending on your performance requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend, I was able to find a solution to this. My ranges are held in a simple `class` like this since I also have other data properties I track along with the `begin` and `end` values of the range.

```dart
class TextBitPack {
  int begin;
  int end;

  TextBitPack({
    required this.begin,
    required this.end,
  });
}
```

I pass in existing ranges like this:

```dart
final ranges = [
  TextBitPack(begin: 5, end: 9),
  TextBitPack(begin: 13, end: 16),
];
```

And the max length of the range of the `stringLength` I'm parsing.

Here is the range parser:

```dart
List<TextBitPack> getTextRanges(List<TextBitPack> ranges, int stringLength) {
  //If the string is empty, we're done
  if (ranges.isEmpty) return [];
  TextBitPack current = ranges.first;

  List<TextBitPack> ready = [];

  //Find the first range which always starts with 0
  if (current.begin > 0) {
    ready.add(
      TextBitPack(begin: 0, end: current.begin),
    );
  }

  //Iterate through all the ranges
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length - 1; i++) {
    final range1 = ranges[i];
    final range2 = ranges[i + 1];

    if (range1.end == range2.begin) {
      ready.add(ranges[i]);
    } else {
      ready.add(range1);
      final newPack = TextBitPack(begin: range1.end, end: range2.begin, entityType: null);
      ready.add(newPack);
    }
  }

  ready.add(ranges.last);

  //Set last range end based on stringLength
  if (ranges.last.end < stringLength) {
    ready.add(
      TextBitPack(
        begin: ranges.last.end,
        end: stringLength,
      ),
    );
  }

  return ready;
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone.